# Custom axis labels with missing table rows

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, axis-labels

There is a Spreadsheet with two columns: Date, Integer. And some rows are missing.
When I *insert chart* manually, I see long horizontal line instead of missing rows.
But when I do this:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0];
  var table = Charts.newDataTable().
    addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Date").
    addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "asd");
  sheet.getSheetValues(sheet.getLastRow() - 9, 1, 10, 2).forEach( function(line) {
    var date = new Date(line[0]);
    table.addRow( [
      date.getDate() + " " + ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"][date.getMonth()],
      line[1]
    ] );
  } );
  var chart = Charts.newLineChart().
    setDataTable(table).
    setXAxisTitle("Date").
    setYAxisTitle("asd").
    setTitle("asd").
    build();
  var temp = "<img src=\'cid:asd\'/>";
  MailApp.sendEmail("asd@gmail.com", "asd", temp, {
    htmlBody: temp,
    inlineImages: { asd: chart }
  } );
```

the X axis is collapsed, because its values aren't actually Dates, because I reformatted them.

[image]
(red lines were made in mspaint to focus your attention)

What is a proper way to make it with horizontal line, like in Spreadsheet, and with customly formatted Dates, like in the image from email?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do this it will take the regular behavior in this case make the connection between available values.

If you change the type of chart, it would illustrate missing values more appropriately; bars or other type of charts would illustrate in a better way missing values.